# Publishing with ArcGIS Server within ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to share map layers and a geoprocessing tool built in ModelBuilder to ArcGIS Server within ArcGIS Pro, but despite being signed into the server manager as an admin user, and signed in to share content, I have no option to publish within Pro.

[image]

Comment: Are you running stand-alone ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS Enterprise? If so what versions? Stand-alone requires version 10.6 or up.

Answer (score 1):

The services in ArcGIS Pro are published in Layers added into a Map. The Layer has Sharing option into right-click menu.

Try the official documentation:
[Share a web feature layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/overview/web-feature-layer.htm)

Geoprocessing Tools/Services has a standard steps to follow.

Try the official documentation:
[Publish geoprocessing services in ArcGIS Pro](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/share-analysis/publishing-geoprocessing-service-in-arcgis-pro.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The solution ended up being that rather than sharing as a web tool, I needed to share the geoprocessing tool as an offline service definition, then publish from ArcGIS Server in the browser.